# Converting a row read with F#-data to array

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to read a csv file (without headers) using F#-data. So far I have got:

```
let filename = @"data.csv"
let file = File.OpenText(filename) 
let data = CsvFile.Load(file)
for row in data.Rows do 
    // ..
```

I would like to convert each row to an array of integers. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row` value is an object that exposes all values of the row via `row.Columns`. This is an array of strings, so you can use `Array.map` and turn each value into a float using the `float` function.

```
for row in data.Rows do
  let asFloatArray = Array.map float row.Columns
  printfn "%A" asFloatArray // TODO: Do something useful here :-)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do it without the for-loop so it could be piped into `map`?